# How come I can change my PATH to gibberish and still use commands?

Tags: environment-variables, ls, command, path, executable

The environment variable PATH is the search path for executable commands, so I thought changing the PATH to something that doesn't exist (for instance, `export PATH=blah`) would make me unable to use any command.

After I change it, it doesn't let me use all commands (e.g. I can't use `ls`). But apparently, I can still use numerous commands, and I can still use `export` and change it back.

Aren't all commands just executable files in the search path? Where are the executable files for these still-usable commands located? How come I can still use them when my search path is gibberish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still run builtin commands, i.e. commands internal to your shell thus not needing to be backed by an executable.

For example, if your shell is `bash`, you can have a look to:  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html

Note that some commands that internally affect the shell like `cd`, `exec` and `exit` for example can't be provided by an external binary because they just wouldn't work as expected (at all even).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your shell is `bash`, there are many shell builtins, shell keywords, shell aliases, such as the shell builtins:

`alias, bg, bind, break, builtin, case, cd, command, compgen, complete, continue, declare, dirs, disown, echo, enable, eval, exec,  exit,  export,  fc,  fg,  getopts, hash, help, history, if, jobs, kill, let, local, logout, popd, printf, pushd, pwd, read,  readonly,  return,  set,  shift,  shopt,  source, suspend,  test,  times,  trap,  type, typeset, ulimit, umask, unalias, unset, until, wait, while`

The following will still work:

```
echo "Hello, world!'

cd /opt

printf '%s\n' /home/user/*

exit
```